# Remove footer from Vertica's Copy Script

Tags: linux, sed, copy, vertica, vsql

I have a vertica copy script (A.copy.vsql) which is loading data into a table from a file which has HEADER, TRAILER and DETAIL RECORDS.

Vertica Copy statement can skip 1 record which means I know how to remove the header.

I want to know if I can chop the trailer in the same way or not?

Also, if I cannot chop it like the header then can I write simple linux SED commands in the VSQL itself (A.copy.vsql) to do the job?

Comment: You can not do it with Vertica or vsql. You could perhaps do a `COPY FROM STDIN` and stream the file in using sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the first and last line from a file you can use:

```
sed '1d;$d' file
```

And used in a command, with the pattern `command file`,
one can, with bash, use a process substitution:

```
command <(sed '1d;$d' file)
```

`1` and `$` are absolute addresses, 1 means first line, while `$` means last.
`d` deletes the line addressed.

`<(...)` is a process substitution.

Comment: I also wanted to use bash command SED, my only question is: Can I write SED in the VSQL file or should I make another script before calling my VSQL?